# How do I store and retrieve an NSMutableDictionary to and from NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

I tried to do this to store an empty dictionary in NSUserDefaults.

```
NSMutableDictionary* fruits = [NSMutableDictionary alloc];
[defaults setObject:fruits forKey:@"fruits"];
```

and then later this to retrieve it.

```
NSMutableDictionary* fruits = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[defaults objectForKey:@"fruits"]];
```

However, retrieving the dictionary crashes my application. Why? How do I store a dictionary in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Are you sure that the crash happens when it's retrieved?  The first line is missing `init`, which should cause a crash when it's added to `defaults`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You get a immutable dictionary back. You do not need to "capsulate" it in another dictionary. If you want to make it mutable write:

```
NSMutableDictionary* animals = [[defaults objectForKey:@"animals"] mutableCopy];
```

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData.
>
> Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a
>   mutable object as the value. For example, if you set a mutable string
>   as the value for "MyStringDefault", the string you later retrieve
>   using stringForKey: will be immutable.
>
> Note: The user defaults system, which you programmatically access through the NSUserDefaults class, uses property lists to store objects representing user preferences. This limitation would seem to exclude many kinds of objects, such as NSColor and NSFont objects, from the user default system. But if objects conform to the NSCoding protocol they can be archived to NSData objects, which are property list–compatible objects. For information on how to do this, see ““Storing NSColor in User Defaults”“; although this article focuses on NSColor objects, the procedure can be applied to any object that can be archived.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thank you, why do I get an immutable dictionary back?

Comment: Updated the answer; because NSDictionary is a superclass of NSMutableDictionary and NSUserDefaults will automatically "convert" it when you save it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

Save:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:mutableArray];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:stack forKey:@"Your Key"];
```

Retrieve:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to init your dictionary and set is as object later. This way works, it's the same as your example but just with properly initialization.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"someValue", @"someKey", nil];
[defaults setObject:dict forKey:@"slovnik"];
[dict release];
NSLog(@"READ: %@", [defaults objectForKey:@"slovnik"]);
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[defaults objectForKey:@"slovnik"]];
NSLog(@"READ2: %@", newDict);
```

Now I get to log console and app do not crash:

```
2012-04-12 08:47:55.030 Test[12179:f803] READ: {
someKey = someValue;
}
2012-04-12 08:47:55.031 Test[12179:f803] READ2: {
someKey = someValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableDictionary* fruits = [NSMutableDictionary alloc];
```

should be

```
NSMutableDictionary* fruits = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

You need to always initialize objects after allocating them.